# highlight controls on submit

Tags: .net, validation, controls, highlight

is there a way to change the color of the controls that didn't pass validation after submitting a form in .net?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

All controls have a [BackColor property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-en/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor.aspx) that can be used to change the background color.

**EDIT**:
It seems you question is actually more about how to perform validation of your form. You should read through the examples on the [CausesValidaion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation.aspx) property and see how Validators are used in a method that subscribes to the button's Click event.

Comment: yeah but do you know what function needs to be modified to change the background color on submit?

Comment: You have to give more information to answer that question. Are you using winforms, WPF or ASP?

Comment: I'm creating a form using ASP.NET C#

Comment: I'd concur with this answer and say you need to read up on .Net validation techniques.